# Conan: How to get the exact version of a statically linked library contained in a pre-built package?

Tags: static-libraries, static-linking, conan, conan-2

I used the following command to get a list of pre-built packages for the libpng library:

```
conan download libpng/1.6.40 -p "arch=x86_64 AND os=Windows AND compiler=msvc AND compiler.version=192" -r conancenter -f json
```

Besides other information, I get the following info:

```
                        "requires": [
                                "zlib/1.3.Z"
                            ]
                        }
```

I get the path to the downloaded pre-built package like this:
`conan cache path libpng/1.6.40:2dc71d849fb2a3eea8f4b3bf24e7117c93b68a8a` (the last part being the package id from the `conan download` output).

How can I find out which exact version of zlib was used to build this pre-built libpng `.lib` file? The conan download information just gives me a `Z` for the last part of the version.

I also looked into `conan graph info` command, but couldn't figure out if this can help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Conan packages do not contain by default the declaration of the exact version and revision that the binary used to link. The `"zlib/1.3.Z"` that is being listed is the "binary compatibility" declaration, saying that this built binary can be used with any patch version of zlib/1.3 without necessarily recompiling itself.

If you want to store an exact copy of the dependencies versions when building a package, it can be done with:

- Modifying a recipe, you can generate a file in your preferred format iterating `self.dependencies`. This might be done in the `generate()` method if you want to do it pre-build, or during the `build()` or even in the `package()` method. Using something like `dep.ref`, [read this section](https://docs.conan.io/2/reference/conanfile/attributes.html#dependencies)
- Without modifying the recipe, and applying it to all packages being built, you can add the same logic as above, but inside a hook ([read this section](https://docs.conan.io/2/reference/extensions/hooks.html)). A post/pre generate/build/package might be ok for this.

Comment: So there is no standard way to find out for the pre-compiled packages in conancenter @drodri?

Comment: Not for the pre-built binaries in ConanCenter, no